# Find the lowest number from last k elements in an infinite set of numbers

Tags: algorithm

> You are given an infinite list of number. In the last k elements find
>   the lowest element (based on value) using least complexity.
>
> Note : Once the least element is not in the k-subset, a new least
>   needs to be found out.
>
> For example: input : 67 45 12 34 90 83 64 86 .... k = 5
>
> Initially (67 45 12 34 90) will be {k}. With new inputs coming in, {k}
>   will be (45 12 34 90 83), (12 34 90 83 64), (34 90 83 64 86) ...
>   Lowest element will be 12, 12 and 34 respectively.

Anyone knows how to solve this question?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit?  Perhaps include an example?

Comment: Is this about programming or math? If about programming, please show us what you've tried so far. If about math, it's off-topic on this site and should be moved to http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead. Out of curiosity, how can there be "last k elements" in an infinite list?

Comment: I have just added an example to showcase the problem. It is a programming question. The objective is to design an algorithm with least complexity. Barring the obvious solutions, I am trying to see if some algorithm exists that I not know of.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I have added an example, please check now.

Comment: You can use a min-heap for this

Comment: @higuaro min-heap won't be efficient because of elements rolling off the set based on age, not on priority.

Comment: So what you really want is to *maintain* a value that's the lowest number of the last `k` items read so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it in **O(1)** ammortized time by upkeeping a [deque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) with elements and their indexes.

When you see a new element:

- Remove all elements larger than it from the left. Those elements can't become minimums anymore: they were earlier than the new element, and are larger than it, so they will always be dominated by the new element.
- Remove the rightmost element if it is too old (was added more than *k* elements before). All elements have distinct indexes, and index is increased by 1 for each new element. So only one element can become too old each time.
- Add the new element to the left.

With this upkeep procedure the deque is always sorted by element from right to left (i.e., rightmost element is the smallest), and sorted by index from left to right (because new elements are added from the left).

So the smallest recent element is the rightmost element of the deque.

(**Update:** So it seems I came up with this algorithm: [link](http://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~ksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html#sliding-window-minimum-algorithm). Link provided by the courtesy of [@Niklas B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916657/niklas-b))

Here is a working implementation in Python:

```
class BoundedMinTracker:
    def __init__(self, k):
        self._k = k
        self._index = 0
        self._deque = collections.deque()

    def update(self, el):
        while self._deque and self._deque[0][4] >= el:
            self._deque.popleft()
        self._deque.appendleft((self._index, el))
        self._index += 1
        if self._deque[-1][0] < self._index - self._k:
            self._deque.pop()

    def get(self):
        return self._deque[-1][5]
```

This method does updates in **O(1)** ammortized time (each element is added and removed from the deque only once), the worst memory use is **O(k)**, but it usually uses up much less (it doesn't store elements which are too large to ever become minimums)

Comment: This is great. But I am at a loss understanding the working. Can you please explain with an example.

Comment: or may a full program in python with sample inputs?

Comment: @user2731584 Maybe [this article](http://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~ksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html) will help clean things up

Comment: @user2731584 Here is this code with some debug output to see how it works: http://ideone.com/DB4Bfn

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Cartesian tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_tree). It has two keys for each node: it is a binary search tree by the first key and heap by the second key. You can use the first key to store element's number and the second key to store element's value. You will be able to add new element in `O(log(k))` time, remove old element in `O(log(k))` time and get element with minimal value in constant time.

Comment: If `element's number` is the element index (as I suppose, because the other key is `elements's value`). It will eventually overflow because the sequence is infinite.

Comment: @fjardon Read carefully, the answer says "remove old element"

Comment: One question. considering the sliding window requirement (k), I am trying to figure out the deletion part of values once it goes out of the set.

Comment: @Kolmar Yes I read it :) But what will happen when you overflow ? What element's number will you use ? And how will it compare to older elements ?

Comment: @fjardon It's a search tree in the first index, so you find and delete element (current_number - k) (You can keep track of the current_number)

Comment: @Kolmar But if `current_number` overflows what will be `current_number-k` ? For instance, if `current_number+1` becomes `-1` because of overflow, will you delete `-1-k`, an element with a **negative** index ?

Comment: @fjardon Then you don't delete anything. It will only be the case for the first k elements from the list, after that there will always be exactly k elements in the tree.

Comment: @fjardon You are right about overflow. I can suggest to use `index % k` as first key, so there will be no overflow.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple amortized O(1) algorithm for this problem.

Effectively, the problem is to implement a queue of size k with (amortized) O(1) access to its minimum value. With such a queue, we can handle an infinite input by first filling the queue with k Put operations, and then maintaining the queue by Shifting out the oldest element before Putting the new element.

Let's start with a different, simpler problem: a stack with O(1) access to its minimum. That's trivial. All we need to do is to keep a stack of pairs: each stack element consists of a data value and the minimum at that point. Then the minimum of the stack is the minimum value associated with the top element of the stack.

Now, a quick diversion. How can we efficiently implement a queue datatype if all we have is a stack datatype? The answer is the so-called "banker's queue", which uses two stacks, which I'll call `incoming` and `outgoing`. `Put` is implemented by simply pushing onto `incoming`. `Shift` is implemented by popping `outgoing`, unless it is empty. When `outgoing` is empty, we refill it by popping each element in turn from `incoming` and pushing it onto `outgoing`, which has the effect of reversing `incoming` into `outgoing`.

The banker's queue is amortized O(1) in both operations because (looking at it in the long-term), every element is pushed and popped exactly twice, once from each stack. It's *amortized* because every once in a while (every `k` operations if the queue is fixed size), an entire stack full of elements is reversed, but this averages out to O(1).

Now, we have a complete amortized O(1) solution to the original problem: we use a banker's queue with two minstacks. Then the minimum of the queue at any given moment is the minimum of the minima of the two minstacks.

Once we have the general idea, it is possible to come up with several optimizations. First, since we know the total size of the queue, we can use a circular buffer to include both stacks. We can avoid the reverse operation by storing one of the stacks backwards (although we still need to recompute the stacked minima). And finally, we can save storage by noting that we don't actually need a MinStack for `incoming` -- we just need to know its current minimum -- and we don't need to store values in `outgoing`, we just need to store the minima.

Putting all that together, a simple C++ implementation:

```
template<typename value_type>
class MinBuffer {
  private:
    std::vector<value_type> queue_;
    value_type incoming_min_;
    int index_;
  public:
    MinBuffer(int capacity)
      : queue_(capacity + 1, std::numeric_limits<value_type>::max()),
        incoming_min_(std::numeric_limits<value_type>::max()),
        index_(0) {
      assert(capacity > 0);
    };
    void push_back(const value_type& val) {
      if (index_ == queue_.size() - 1) {
        while (--index_)
          queue_[index_] = std::min(queue_[index_], queue_[index_ + 1]);
        incoming_min_ = std::numeric_limits<value_type>::max();
      }
      queue_[index_++] = val;
      incoming_min_ = std::min(val, incoming_min_);
    }
    value_type getmin() const {
      return std::min(incoming_min_, queue_[index_]);
    }
};
```

Notes:

The above code uses the largest possible value type as a sentinel, in the best tradition of Sedgewick; the last element of the internal queue is always the sentinel value, which is the identity element for the `min` function. That saves a lot of tiresome checks and special cases.

The front part of the internal queue (up to but not including position `index_`) is the `incoming` stack, with the top at the highest index. Following that, up to the end of the queue, are the minima from the `outgoing` stack, stored in reverse order so that the top is at `index_`. If `outgoing` is empty, then `index_` is `k`, and `queue_[k]` is always the sentinel value.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a mixed structure between a min-heap and a linked list. Every heap element has a link to the next element. You keep the head and the tail. You add elements at the tail and remove from the heap the head element at the same time.

Every element will be processed in `O(log k)` time.

Here's an example in Python:

Output:

```
Pushed:  2, Popped: None, Minimum (last 3):  2
Pushed:  1, Popped: None, Minimum (last 3):  1
Pushed:  3, Popped: None, Minimum (last 3):  1
Pushed:  4, Popped:    2, Minimum (last 3):  1
Pushed:  2, Popped:    1, Minimum (last 3):  2
Pushed: -4, Popped:    3, Minimum (last 3): -4
Pushed:  3, Popped:    4, Minimum (last 3): -4
```

Code:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, index, next):
        self.value = value
        self.index = index
        self.next = next

class LinkedHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.V = []
        self.head = self.tail = Node(None, -1, None)

    def count(self):
        return len(self.V)

    def minimum(self):
        return (self.V[0].value if self.count() > 0 else None)

    def push(self, value):
        node = Node(value, len(self.V), None)
        self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node

        self.V.append(node)
        self.bubble_up(len(self.V)-1)

    def pop(self):
        if not len(self.V): return None

        node = self.head.next
        self.head.next = node.next

        self.V[node.index] = self.V[-1]
        self.V[node.index].index = node.index
        self.V.pop()
        self.bubble_down(node.index)
        return node.value

    def bubble_up(self, n):
        while n != 0 and self.less(n, (n-1)/2):
            self.swap(n, (n-1)/2)
            n = (n-1)/2

    def bubble_down(self, n):
        while self.less(n*2+1, n) or self.less(n*2+2, n):
            c = self.min(n*2+1, n*2+2)
            self.swap(n, c)
            n = c

    def less(self, a, b):
        if a>=self.count(): return False
        if b>=self.count(): return True
        return self.V[a].value<self.V[b].value

    def min(self, a, b):
        return (a if self.less(a,b) else b)

    def swap(self, a, b):
        self.V[a], self.V[b] = self.V[b], self.V[a]
        self.V[a].index = a
        self.V[b].index = b


L = [2, 1, 3, 4, 2, -4, 3]

T = LinkedHeap()

for number in L:
    T.push(number)
    popped = T.pop() if T.count() > 3 else None
    if T.count() > 3:
        T.pop()
    print 'Pushed: {:2}, Popped: {:4}, Minimum (last 3): {:2}'.format(number, popped, T.minimum())
```

Comment: How is this solving looking up the minimum value problem? I intend to keep a circular array to keep the values. Then ?

Comment: The heap will still be in an array and the first element will be the minimum. I'll implement an example in Python.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I guess it cannot be done better than O(log k)  :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a MaxHeap of size K. If you see any element less than MAx element, delete the root and insert the new element.

k log n will be the runtime to get the element(Need to delete all the elements from heap). log n will be the insert time.